# Does adding a picture to a previous answer make it sufficiently original?

Tags: discussion, images

I was noticing as a pattern with upvoting when browsing the highest voted questions. It seems to be a very good "strategy" to find highly viewed questions, summarize the other answers, and then add a picture. It sounds simple enough but can generate hundreds of reputation points over a relatively short period of time.

Example: [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage/42469170#42469170)

Is an answer considered original enough if only an illustration is added?

Comment: Imagine if you couldn't actually see the picture.  Imagine hearing the answer through a tool like NVDA or Dragon NaturallySpeaking.  What actual *value* would the picture have if the text above it can't answer well enough?

Comment: By "pattern", do you mean you found at least a single user doing this at least more than once?

Comment: What content from that answer do you think is plagiarized?  What portions of the answer, outside of the image, do you think aren't their own original work?

Comment: I wouldn't use the word plagiarized, I just meant there isn't any new code there. As for the pattern I alluded to, it was evident in browsing the https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes page, you can pretty much click any answer and compare the vote count on answers with pictures vs those without. It was not my intention to single out a user.

Comment: @oMiKeY So then, contrary to your question, you're not wondering if the content is actually their own original work, but simply whether or not the post is a useful addition.  That's radically different.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is, if an answer adds only an illustration, but no new code, is it meeting the standards of originality required of other answers, or is a visualization alone considered additional information. I have no dog in this race its just something I have observed.

Comment: I think technically "it depends" but in practice probably not. Like in the case of your example: a screenshot of text is not useful. Note that the alt text doesn't even adequately describe what's in it.